# Problemas con realizar un Web-Scrapping "AttributeError: 'NoneType'"

Tags: html, python, pandas, beautifulsoup, web-scrapping

Tengo el siguiente problema al momento de realizar un *webscraping* a la pagina de shein.

En general el problema es de **atributos** y en relación con - `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'` -

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

# Define the URL of the Shein category you want to scrape
url = "https://www.shein.com.mx/style/Women-Clothing-sc-001121425.html?ici=mx_tab01navbar04&src_module=topcat&src_tab_page_id=page_select_class1686667964514&src_identifier=fc%3DWomen%60sc%3DROPA%60tc%3D0%60oc%3D0%60ps%3Dtab01navbar04%60jc%3DitemPicking_001121425&srctype=category&userpath=category-ROPA" 

# Send a GET request to the URL and retrieve the page content
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

# Create empty lists to store the scraped data
products = []
prices = []
urls = []

# Find all product items on the page
product_items = soup.find_all("div", class_="product-list-v2")

# Extract information from each product item
for item in product_items:
    # Extract product name
    product = item.find("div", class_="S-product-item__name").text.strip()
    print(product)
    products.append(product)

    # Extract product price
    price = item.find("span", class_="normal-price-ctn__sale-price").text.strip()
    print(price)
    prices.append(price)
    
    # Extract product URL
    product_url = "https://www.shein.com.mx" + item.find("a", class_="S-product-item__link")["href"]
    print(product_url)
    urls.append(product_url)

# Create a DataFrame from the scraped data
data = {
    "Product": products,
    "Price": prices,
    "URL": urls
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Save the DataFrame to an Excel file
df.to_excel("shein_data.xlsx", index=False)
```

Me aparece el siguiente **error**:

```
Blusa con estampado de manga murciélago
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/mf/q3n84d_56kqg93knb4lwwpk40000gn/T/ipykernel_92687/3928343523.py in 
     26 
     27     # Extract product price
---> 28     price = item.find("span", class_="normal-price-ctn__sale-price").text.strip()
     29     print(price)
     30     prices.append(price)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Según yo el problema se encuentra en darle lectura a la siguiente linea de código:

```
<span role="contentinfo" aria-label="Precio$MXN171.00" class="normal-price-ctn__sale-price" tabindex="0">$MXN171.00</span>
```

Como se podría solucionar este problema?

Comment: Hola Alexis, creo que si cambias **prices** por **price** en la linea conflictiva, se te soluciona el problema

Comment: Hola Marce, si, luego me di cuenta de ello e hice la correccion del texto. Muchas gracias. Pero igual subsanado dicho error, sigue apareciendo el problema de error en el atributo. Quiero que me lea el "MXM171" y no puedo. Tienes alguna sugerencia?

Comment: No soy bueno con HTML, pero creo que es mejor agregarle un "id" y llamarlo por el mismo.